# chaquopy android apk size bigger

Tags: android, performance, chaquopy

I have use chaquopy in android. after generating sign/build APK file. The file size is bigger(around 165 MB). this is too large an APK file.

We need to solution. please help me.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

There are several suggestions in the Chaquopy FAQ under ["How can I make my app smaller?"](https://chaquo.com/chaquopy/doc/current/faq.html#faq-size). In summary:

- Reduce the size of your source code directory.
- Reduce your pip requirements list.
- Reduce the number of ABIs in your app.
- If you're using TensorFlow, switch to TensorFlow Lite.

Comment: I accidentally had a big zip file in the python source code directory and it made my apk 10x larger than it should have been